# Attach method on ViewModel to events in WPF

Tags: wpf, events, mvvm

How can bind an event on a WPF Control to a method on my ViewModel?

I have a ViewModel:

```
class MyViewModel {
    public string MyText { get; set; }
    public void MyMouseHandleMethod(object sender, EventArgs e) { }
}
```

In a DataTemplate I've got:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}">
```

Now I would like to attach a method on my ViewModel to the TextBlock, something like:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding MyText}" MouseUp="{Binding MyMouseHandleMethod}">
```

I cannot figure out how to do this without creating a callback in the Code-behind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into using AttachedCommandBehavior from [here](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/12/13/attachedcommandbehavior-v2-aka-acb/). It allows you to bind Commands to events entirely in XMAL. Not exactly what you want, but it will give you the same outcome.

Answer (score 1):

I have a new solution that works in .NET 4.5+ using a custom markup extension on  the event. It can be used with multiple arguments, bindings and other extensions to provide argument values, etc. I explain it in full detail here:

http://www.singulink.com/CodeIndex/post/building-the-ultimate-wpf-event-method-binding-extension

Usage:

```
<!--  Basic usage  -->
<Button Click="{data:MethodBinding OpenFromFile}" Content="Open" />

<!--  Pass in a binding as a method argument  -->
<Button Click="{data:MethodBinding Save, {Binding CurrentItem}}" Content="Save" />

<!--  Another example of a binding, but this time to a property on another element  -->
<ComboBox x:Name="ExistingItems" ItemsSource="{Binding ExistingItems}" />
<Button Click="{data:MethodBinding Edit, {Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=ExistingItems}}" />

<!--  Pass in a hard-coded method argument, XAML string automatically converted to the proper type  -->
<ToggleButton Checked="{data:MethodBinding SetWebServiceState, True}"
                Content="Web Service"
                Unchecked="{data:MethodBinding SetWebServiceState, False}" />

<!--  Pass in sender, and match method signature automatically -->
<Canvas PreviewMouseDown="{data:MethodBinding SetCurrentElement, {data:EventSender}, ThrowOnMethodMissing=False}">
    <controls:DesignerElementTypeA />
    <controls:DesignerElementTypeB />
    <controls:DesignerElementTypeC />
</Canvas>

    <!--  Pass in EventArgs  -->
<Canvas MouseDown="{data:MethodBinding StartDrawing, {data:EventArgs}}"
        MouseMove="{data:MethodBinding AddDrawingPoint, {data:EventArgs}}"
        MouseUp="{data:MethodBinding EndDrawing, {data:EventArgs}}" />

<!-- Support binding to methods further in a property path -->
<Button Content="SaveDocument" Click="{data:MethodBinding CurrentDocument.DocumentService.Save, {Binding CurrentDocument}}" />
```

View model method signatures:

```
public void OpenFromFile();
public void Save(DocumentModel model);
public void Edit(DocumentModel model);

public void SetWebServiceState(bool state);

public void SetCurrentElement(DesignerElementTypeA element);
public void SetCurrentElement(DesignerElementTypeB element);
public void SetCurrentElement(DesignerElementTypeC element);

public void StartDrawing(MouseEventArgs e);
public void AddDrawingPoint(MouseEventArgs e);
public void EndDrawing(MouseEventArgs e);

public class Document
{
    // Fetches the document service for handling this document
    public DocumentService DocumentService { get; }
}

public class DocumentService
{
    public void Save(Document document);
}
```