# How can I bind to Methods rather than Variables in WPF following MVVM structure?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

While doing WPF with MVVM structure, I always bind my View to ViewModel using Getter-Setter on variables of class.
Isn't there anyway such that I can bind to directly Methods of ViewModel?

( Please make sure that as I am using MVVM, I don't expect code behind of view such that  method(sender s,...) )

Comment: what do you want this for?

Comment: @HighCore: Because I feel unnecessary to create variables to just call methods.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Attach method on ViewModel to events in WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361860/attach-method-on-viewmodel-to-events-in-wpf)

Comment: Possible other duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6430256/wpf-event-binding-to-viewmodel-for-non-command-classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can acheive this using interaction triggers which allows you to bind any event to the methods in the viewmodel. [Refer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15488033/textbox-binding-to-both-lostfoucus-and-property-update).

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"

<TextBox Margin="0,287,0,0">
     <i:Interaction.Triggers>
          <i:EventTrigger EventName="LostFocus">
               <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding LostFocusCommand}" />
          </i:EventTrigger>
     </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: Gives Compilations Errors like "Trigger was not found in Interection" as well as "Invoke command doesn't exist in namespace http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"

Comment: download the dll from http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/125188/Using-EventTrigger-in-XAML-for-MVVM-No-Code-Behind

Comment: Sry actually I was in hurry and I got your reply too late.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [Commands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752308(v=vs.110).aspx) in WPF. Which is simply a command patter, which allows you to turn "method" into an object and thus be able to bind it as normal variable.

On the other hand, if you want to "bind to method" just to display it's data, then creating a property is extremely simple. I don't see a problem with this approach.

Comment: You are right but Commands are limited to components like Buttons only.

Comment: @Pratik Would you please specify more what do you want to bind to what? What is your exact problem?

Comment: I want to bind with LostFocus event of TextBox. Its for the validation purpose of content of TextBox.

Comment: @Pratik naturally you don't have to bind methode because you have already bound value (of your textbox) to prop. So you can call methode from props setter. in your case with lostfocus maybe try somthing <TextBox Text="{Binding Description, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" />

Comment: @Pratik Bind the text to a property and set the bindings to update on `LostFocus`. Using the `LostFocus` event is completely unnecessary.

Comment: I have already UpdateSourceTrigger=OnChangeProperty to TextBox, so I have data saved in ViewModel already, Can I just know whether is it possible to bind directly to method in ViewModel or not?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your requirements clearly, but Why don't you create a property and call that method on the get property

Comment: Because I feel unnecessary to create variables to just call methods.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa348824(v=vs.110).aspx, but not sure it will help you